# What colors are allowed in SpreadsheetGear?

Tags: spreadsheetgear

In setting the interior color of a cell, I find that some colors are allowed and some are ignored.  For example, this works (where ws is an IWorksheet object):

```
ws.Cells[r, c].Interior.Color = Colors.LightPink;
```

but when attempting this color

```
ws.Cells[r, c].Interior.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 136, 136);
```

the result is a cell that still has its original white background.  As if the color had never been changed.  Are there only certain colors that SpreadSheetGear will allow you to use?

Comment: I just tested this code but am not reproducing the behavior you describe.  In both cases the expected color is set and rendered (no white bg in the second line of code).  That said, I don't know the surrounding context around your test case so may not be setting my own up like yours.  Can you elaborate on your test case, such as-- are you viewing this resulting file in the WorkbookView control, or saving to a file (XLS / XLSX / XLSM?) and viewing in Excel?

Comment: Hi, Tim.  Thank you for your reply.  The answer is the latter... I am creating a spreadsheet that I am later viewing in Excel.

Comment: I still can't reproduce what you're describing.  Please provide a more concrete and complete test case.

Answer (score 0):

A few years later stumbling on this problem again, I was able to solve it.  The list of colors that you are restricted to can be found by inspecting the Colors property of the IWorkbook object:

```
SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook wb = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook();

for (int i = 0; i < wb.Colors.Count; i++)
    Debug.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", i, wb.Colors[i].ToArgb().ToString("x"));
```

If the color you want is not in this list, then SpreadsheetGear will arbitrarily pick some other color that is in the palette.  However, you are able to the colors you want to the palette.  For example:

```
wb.Colors[wb.Colors.Count - 1] = SpreadsheetGear.Colors.Orange;
```